# Passing search arguments from URL to mobile version of linkedin (touch.www.linkedin)

Tags: url, linkedin-api

I'm trying to pass the arguments for the search from url. When I'm using desktop version, like below, it works fine.

> www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?firstName=John&lastName=Doe

However when I'm using mobile one (touch.www.linkedin.com), it doesn't. Is there any way to pass search arguments via url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linkedin dosen't provide Advanced Search feature for mobile website as you can see in this question from LinkedIn Help Center: [Advanced search on iPhone](https://community.linkedin.com/questions/89814/advanced-search-on-iphone.html)

It depends what are you try to accomplish but i guess the best way to do it is to use [Linkedin API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)

---

**Bonus**

This will be an example of using API in order to use the Advanced Search Feature for the provided "input"

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id))?first-name=foo&last-name=gates
```